# position of the text in html

Tags: html, css

I'd like my text to be under the background image (which doesn't take the whole height of the screen) but I tried many things and nothing worked.

```css
html {
  background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-image: url("concert_bg.jpg");
  background-attachment: scroll;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

h1 {
  border-top: 500px;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  font-size: 10em;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: underline;
  z-index: 5;
}

p {
  color: rgb(255, 255, 0);
}
```

```html
<h1>
  concert
</h1>

<p>
  QUEEN
</p>
```

Comment: Why don't you just make another element to hold the image, since you are essentially creating a masthead/header image with the background image?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if background-image is what you want for this. Use a normal html img and place it above your text.

Edit: Does this match the wanted result?

Add to your CSS:

```
img.cover {
  /* Fits image to width of the display size */
  width: 100%;
}
```

And your HTML:

```
<!--- Replace with your own src --->
<img class="cover"src="https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/C1YRnQIzuTS._SL1000_.png"></img>
<h1>concert</h1>
<p>QUEEN</p>
```

Comment: This is better as a comment (I know you probably can't comment yet), but if you are going to answer, please add code and show what the OP can do.

Comment: Edited. Yes would have commented if I could. :)

Comment: And how can I now put the text "concert" over the image, on the top of the screen and centered ? And the code I sent is all my code, I started learning html this afternoon

Comment: @bappi I would suggest doing some more research and learning before asking questions here. You are essentially asking a new question than what you initially posted.

Comment: well initially I had my background and the title over it, but now that the image is not referenced as background, the title is not over it anymore

Comment: but I understand,  I'll try to find a way to solve this

Comment: If you want "concert" to  be display above the image you have to place the corresponding element (the h1 element) above the img element. I suggest you don't rely on CSS to much for the beginning and use as much HTML as possible to get your page to look like you want to. Once you've got the basics you can spice it up with more CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The html

```
<div class="hero">
    <div>
        <h2>Contact us</h2> // you text on the background, Place as you wish
    </div>
</div>
```

the css

```
.hero {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 400px; //whatever you need here
    background-image: url("/images/hero6.jpg"); //the background image you need
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed; //gives a little parallax effect
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: `className` is not a valid HTML attribute, it should be `class`.

Comment: Also, this doesn't answer the question. The OP wants the content BELOW the image, not on top of it. You should probably use the HTML markup the OP provided or something similar if you are going to answer.

Comment: @disinfor couldnt really understand that from the question, This is what i could best formulate. Feel free to edit to enhance the answer

Comment: I'm not going to edit your answer. The OPs opening line states _I'd like my text to be under the background image_